# concatMap and share to play a series fo observables only once even if multiple subscribers

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to execute some observables in series, which I've done with concatMap, but I want them to be executed only once, even if I have multiple subscribers, I tried the share and shareReplay operators but none of them seems to work.

Here is the code:

```js
import { EMPTY, Observable, BehaviorSubject, of, from, concat, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, map, switchMap, tap, filter, take, share, shareReplay, exhaust, publishLast, refCount } from 'rxjs/operators';


const refreshAccessToken = () => {
  console.log("Start refresh access token")
  return timer(2000);
}

const connect = () => {
  console.log("Start connect")
  return timer(3000)
}

const authent = () => {
  console.log("Start authent")
  return timer(2000)
}

let isAuthenticated = false;
let isExpired = true;

function initSocket(): Observable<any> {
  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    let observable$ = of(1);
    if (isExpired) {
      observable$ = refreshAccessToken();
    }
    return observable$.pipe(
      concatMap(() => connect()),
      concatMap(() => authent()),
      tap(() => {
        isAuthenticated = true;
        console.log("Tap")
      }),
      share()
    );
  }
  return of(1);
}


initSocket().subscribe(() => console.log("Finished 1"))

initSocket().subscribe(() => console.log("Finished 2"))
```

You can find my sample in https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-4memxw?embed=1&file=index.ts

Here the results are :

```
Start refresh access token
Start refresh access token
Start connect
Start connect
Start authent
Start authent
Tap
Finished 1
Tap
Finished 2
```

But what I'm looking for is :

```
Start refresh access token
Start connect
Start authent
Tap
Finished 1
Finished 2
```

Maybe this has already been answered, but I can't see what I'm missing, if someone can help, it would be nice.

**EDIT:**

I'll explain my need maybe I'm tackling the problem in the wrong way.
I'm coding a service class that wraps a socket.io client, every function in this class that emits or listens to a socket.io event, must check if we are connected and authenticated to socket.io.

Here is what needs to be done by the multiple observables, on every subscription:

1. Check if connected
2. If not, check if access token is still
   valid, if yes go to 4
3. If not, refresh the access token
4. Create socket.io connection and wait for connect event
5. On connect event send access_token and wait for response
6. If authentication successful continue to next observable

In this series of observables, the first subscriber will execute all of the observables, if a second subscriber arrives when the observable is executing wait for the same result, do not initiate a connection twice.

If a third or more arrives after the connection is finished, we still need to check if the variable isAuthenticated changed, if it's false, act like the first subscriber, if it's true, continue.

Hope it helps clarify what i'm looking for.

Comment: a stackblitz is great, but the question **itself** should include a [mcve]. This question becomes useless in future if (...when) the link dies.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to assign data to an observable, and then subscribe to that observable, instead of calling `initFunction()` which creates as many observables as there are subscribers. But with assigning data to observable and subscribing to that, prevents this from happening, also using `shareReplay`:

```ts
let obs$ = new Observable();

function initSocket(): void {
  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    let observable$ = of(1);
    if (isExpired) {
      observable$ = refreshAccessToken();
    }
    obs$ = observable$.pipe(
      concatMap(() => connect()),
      concatMap(() => authent()),
      tap(() => {
        isAuthenticated = true;
        console.log("Tap")
      }),
      shareReplay()
    );
  }
}

initSocket();

obs$.subscribe(() => console.log("Finished 1"))

obs$.subscribe(() => console.log("Finished 2"))

setTimeout(() => {
  obs$.subscribe(() => console.log("Finished 3 after 20 seconds"))
}, 20000)
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-4myuur?file=index.ts)**

Comment: This works. But unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem, I don't want to go all over the process if the variable isAuthenticated is true, the issue with this solution is that if I have another subscriber that comes lets say 30s after, the authentication is played again, which is not needed.

Comment: @Abdou, how about `shareReplay()`? here's a third subscriber triggered after 20 seconds: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-4myuur?file=index.ts

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! It's better but still missing the last piece, if the variable isAuthenticated change to false, the observables are not executed again, the variable is not evaluated on every subscription, which is what I'm looking for.